# normalize smooth ndimension dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have following dataframe `df1`, which actually represents grid with coordinates:

```
     latitude  longitude  level            time
0   40.008606  20.114280  880.0  3/31/1981 5:00
1   40.008606  20.114280  880.0  3/31/1981 6:00
2   40.008606  20.114280  880.0  3/31/1981 7:00
3   40.008606  20.114280  880.0  3/31/1981 8:00
4   39.665283  20.097115  855.0  3/31/1981 5:00
5   39.665283  20.097115  855.0  3/31/1981 6:00
6   39.665283  20.097115  855.0  3/31/1981 7:00
7   39.665283  20.097115  855.0  3/31/1981 8:00
8   39.665283  19.911120  860.0  3/31/1981 5:00
9   39.665283  19.911120  860.0  3/31/1981 6:00
10  39.665283  19.911120  860.0  3/31/1981 7:00
11  39.665283  19.911120  860.0  3/31/1981 8:00
```

I want to normalize - interpolate 4d weather data to above grid, whereas `latitude`, `longitude`, `level` and `time` are dimensions. Values in resolution 0.25deg `latitude` and `longitude` and in resolution of 25mbar `level` are in below dataframe `df2`:

```
    latitude  level  longitude            time          t
0      40.00  875.0      20.00  3/31/1981 5:00   7.622246
1      40.00  875.0      20.00  3/31/1981 6:00   8.832257
2      40.00  875.0      20.00  3/31/1981 7:00   1.107310
3      40.00  875.0      20.00  3/31/1981 8:00  11.144372
4      40.00  900.0      20.00  3/31/1981 5:00   8.736878
..       ...    ...        ...             ...        ...
66     40.25  900.0      20.25  3/31/1981 8:00   6.014550
67     40.25  850.0      20.25  3/31/1981 5:00   6.729872
68     40.25  850.0      20.25  3/31/1981 6:00   8.098390
69     40.25  850.0      20.25  3/31/1981 7:00   5.234497
70     40.25  850.0      20.25  3/31/1981 8:00   5.968091
```

Entire dataframe is on [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMkNtiI05PfN7BvM21Zg?e=QEasAM). So, what I need is column `t` of dataframe `df2` spread-normalized over dataframe `df1` in form of new column in `df1`. Hope desired output is clear.

So far, i am considering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900969/4d-interpolation-for-irregular-x-y-z-grids-by-python/47902153#47902153) solution, but It uses same datatype for all dimensions, which is not case here. I managed to find nearest `latitude`, `longitude`,`level` of `df2` and add those columns to df1 and then use:

```
rslt= pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["latitude","level","longitude"],how="left")
```

but this only gets nearest member, not smooth, interpolated value over above dimensions.

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you convert your data to an xarray Dataset and then use its multidimensional interpolation capability:

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html#multi-dimensional-interpolation